# Am I closing this Oracle pooled connection correctly?

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle

I am attempting to use a pooled connection for my web application in Java. I am using an Oracle database and here is my code:

```
public class DatabaseHandler
{

    static private Connection m_database = null;

    static private OracleConnectionPoolDataSource pooledSource = null;

    /**
     * Attempts to open an Oracle database located at the specified serverName and port.
     * @param serverName Address of the server.
     * @param portNumber Port to connect to.
     * @param sid SID of the server.
     * @param userName Username to login with.
     * @param password Password to login with.
     * @throws WebApplicationException with response code 500 Internal Server Error.
     */
    static public void openDatabase(String userName, String password,String serverName,int portNumber, String sid)
    throws WebApplicationException
    {
        try
        {
            // Load the JDBC driver
            String driverName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
            Class.forName(driverName);

            // Create a connection to the database
            String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + serverName + ":" + portNumber + ":" + sid;
            pooledSource = new OracleConnectionPoolDataSource();

            pooledSource.setUser(userName);
            pooledSource.setURL(url);
            pooledSource.setPassword(password);
            m_database = pooledSource.getConnection();

        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
        {
            // Could not find the database driver
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            // Could not connect to the database
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Attempts to execute the specified SQL query.
     * @throws WebApplicationException with a response code of Bad Request
     * if the query is invalid SQL.
     */
    static public ResultSet makeQuery(String query) throws WebApplicationException
    {
        ResultSet rs = null;
        if (m_database != null)
        {
            try 
            {
                Statement stmt = m_database.createStatement();
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            }
            catch (SQLException e)
            {
                // invalid query
                System.out.println(query);
                throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
        }        
        return rs;
    }

    /**
     * Attempts to close the database. 
     * @throws WebApplicationException with a response code of  500 Server error
     */
    static public void closeDatbase() throws WebApplicationException
    {
        try
        {
            m_database.close();
            pooledSource.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

I am doing this in Eclipse and I have a warning that `pooledSource.close()` is deprecated. I have never used a pooled connection before and I just want to be sure that I am doing everything correctly. Is there a better way to close an Oracle pooled resource?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A deprecated method means that this method shouldn't be used. In future releases, the `close()` method can be purged entirely. I suggest removing `pooledSource.close()`.

Also, I would suggest not to have a static instance of a `Connection` and `DataSource` as you require a connection on request and not keep it alive throughout the application. Always close a `ResultSet` first and then a `Connection` and **guarantee** the closure by adding them in a `finally` block.

Comment: So I do not need to explicitly close the pooled connection, it is handled for me? I figured that might be the case but I wanted to be 100% sure so I don't abandon the connection instead of closing it.

Comment: You don't need to close connection pool. If you got the connection from the pool, the `Connection` is of a pooled connection, so closing the connection returns itself to the pool.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation.

Comment: I am surprised to see this answer accepted. The question is about closing a pooled connection correctly. And the answer is about something different: The answer is about closing the connection pool.

Btw: The closing of the pooled connection in the question is at least very error prone. In my opinion it is negligent handled.

Comment: @Fatal, if you see the question, you will see that the OP referred to deprecation of the `close()` method. Also, A normal and a PooledConnection are 2 totally different connections, whereas closing pooled connections returns itself to the pool and closing the normal connection closes every instances that is connected to the RDBMS itself.

Comment: I know about the difference but it does not make a difference how they should be handled.

For the rest ok: He asked at last about the deprecated method. Nevertheless I never would accept such code, because it is very bad. Sorry that I've to say that.

Comment: @Fatal I may have worded my question incorrectly, I meant to ask how to close a connection pool, not a pooled connection. Also, I am merely an intern that is still in college using Java/connecting to a database for the first time, I would love to make my code better. How specifically is my code error prone? I know you say I should close the connection where it is used but how is this different than calling closeDatabase() where I am using the connection?

Comment: @SC Ghost No problem. Slow going is all trucks beginning. I edited my answer with some sample code.

Comment: Changed my vote since you added most important "fixes" to your answer. So from -1 to +1 you got +2 with that. :-)

Answer (score 1):

1. The connection must be closed to be returned to the pool.
2. Always close your connection in a finally-block.
3. Never hold connection references as a class member - this is error prone and bad design. Connections should be aquired as late as possible and released as soon as possible. It does not make sense to hold something like that as class member.
4. Close connections where they are used. Your code is error prone again here. If you forget to call `closeDatabase()` you're leaking connections.

Attention:
Do not jumble closing the `connection` and closing the `connection pool` here.

Because it was requested here's some code for correct and good connection handling:

```
public void doSomethingWithDb(Connection con, ...) {
    boolean release = (con == null);

    try {
        con = PersistenceUtils.getConnection(con); //static helper return a new conenction from pool when provided con==null otherwise simply returns the given con

        //do something

        if(release) {
            con.commit();
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException e) {
        //handle errors, i.e. calling con.rollback() but be sure to check for con!=null before. Again maybe null-safe static helper method here.
    }
    finally {
        if(release && con!=null){
            con.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I am using Connection as method parameter in order to be able to call many of such methods in one db transaction. But you can always put `null` as first argument for Connection and the method get a connection from pool for you.

When you call another "DB-Method" inside a "DB-Method" you just provide your connection to the underlying method - so you have everything in one transaction then.

As you see correct JDBC code produces much boilerplate code. In the first step you can reduce it by implementing a Utility-Class like PersistenceUtils which provides static null-safe methods like commit(Connection), rollback(Connection), getConnection(Connection), close(Connection) ...
With that you get rid of all null-checks and you can include logging or something else there, too.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman Call close() on the connection object. Maybe it is also checked for returning to the pool when Garbage Collected (I do not know), but since it is important to return it to the pool as fast as possible you must call it yourself. Follow step 2 to do this the right way - always close such resources in a finally block.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have applied the suggestions that you supplied here.